# Why does multiplication repeats the number several times?

Tags: python, string, multiplication

I don't know how to multiply in Python.

If I do this:

```
price = 1 * 9
```

It will appear like this:

```
111111111
```

And the answer needs to be `9` (`1x9=9`)

How can I make it multiply correctly?

Comment: "Multiply" is the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 18):

Only when you multiply integer with a string, you will get repetitive string..

You can use `int()` factory method to create integer out of string form of integer..

```
>>> int('1') * int('9')
9
>>> 
>>> '1' * 9
'111111111'
>>>
>>> 1 * 9
9
>>> 
>>> 1 * '9'
'9'
```

- If **both operands are ints**, you will get multiplication of them as int.
- If **one operand is an int and the other is a string**, then the string will be repeated the number of times specified by the int.

Answer (score 9):

It's the difference between strings and integers.  See:

```
>>> "1" * 9
'111111111'

>>> 1 * 9
9
```

Answer (score 3):

Use integers instead of strings.

make sure to cast your string to ints

`price = int('1') * 9`

The actual example code you posted will return `9` not `111111111`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused about types here. You'll only get that result if you're multiplying a string. Start the interpreter and try this:

```
>>> print "1" * 9
111111111
>>> print 1 * 9
9
>>> print int("1") * 9
9
```

So make sure the first operand is an integer (and not a string), and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Should work:

```
In [1]: price = 1*9

In [2]: price
Out[2]: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot multiply an integer by a string. To be sure, you could try using the int (short for integer which means whole number) command, like this for example -

```
firstNumber = int(9)
secondNumber = int(1)
answer = (firstNumber*secondNumber)
```

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [58]: price = 1 *9
In [59]: price
Out[59]: 9
```